# Prevent page indexing externally _without_ affecting internal google site search?

Tags: google-search, canonical-url, noindex, google-programmable-search-engine

Is it possible to prevent google search from indexing a page, but still allow that page to be indexed by the custom search engine used for on-site search?

Our presenting problem concerns content we have licensed to another web site. Naturally, we don't want this indexed as duplicate content, so we provided canonical urls with the initial content delivery. However, the canonical urls they display on each page have gone out of date and correcting them is a sizable lift.

Initially we were tempted to simply noindex the content pages, but then we realized that the client uses a google CSE (custom search engine, formerly known as "google site search") to power their on-site search. It seems like if we noindex the content, that will break their site search since that appears to be one of the preferred ways to prevent CSE from indexing pages.

Another way to look at this question is: does google CSE actually index your site separately from google search, or is CSE just a filtered version of the global google index? (If the content is not indexed separately, then it would follow that you cannot manage google search and CSE searches separately.)

Comment: *Is it possible to prevent google search from indexing a page, but still allow that page to be indexed by the custom search engine used for on-site search?* No. They are essentially the same thing. Canonical tags are the way to go.

Comment: You can kind of do it the reverse though. You can give parts of your page a class of "nocontent" and the Google CSE will ignore it for site search indexing purposes.

Comment: You could buy a Google Search Appliance to index your website for site search: https://enterprise.google.com/search/products/gsa.html